Output Resistance in Cadence


Hello, I am trying to find out output resistance of opamp. Is the way that put the small signal model source at the output, set the voltage at operating point 0.9028V, and set the AC amplitude for 5mV. After DC and AC swept, we got the output resistance from AC amplitude dividing by current. Should I turn of  ac amplitude for VIN+ and VIN-? Is it correct approach? Thanks for helping.
Reference: My screenshot from virtuoso

Easiest is to use an AC 1 source with a DC value of your choice, then plot Zout = 1/(current flowing through the VDC source) across frequency.

https://imgur.com/a/BiKECU5
Is this what you said?
Should I turn off the ac voltage?
I am a little bit confused.
Thank you

@jsdklfsldn looks about right. The voltage source you can omit in the expression as it's simply equal to 1.

How about ac voltage of differntial pair? Should they be turned off? Thanks a lot

@jsdklfsldn off at AC, but with a well-defined DC common-mode level at their gates. You will not get anything useful if they are grounded.

I am currious that if turn off ac, does simulation take into account of M4 CLM?

@jsdklfsldn What is CLM? By "turning off AC" (which might have not been a good choice of words), I mean that the only active AC source should be at the output, while the rest should be off, yet providing a DC bias. M4 also needs a bias at the gate, and I would do it out of a current mirror instead of what you do.

CLM represents for channel length modulation.
Could you say it clearly on last sentence? Thank you

@jsdklfsldn as long you're using a transistor model from a PDK foundry, CLM must be considered on it. It's such a basic transistor effect, I would be surprised if it weren't modeled.

@jsdklfsldn any other question? I think I already answered your main question and all the 2ndary ones.

How about calculating overall transconductance? Thanks

@jsdklfsldn please ask another question. I know what you need to do but I can't answer an ever-expanding question. Please mark my answer as correct if I have answered your main question about simulating Zout, unless there's something not clear about it.

Do I need post a new article? Thanks
